# Numeric Map Over With Functor

Tags: scala, typeclass, functor

I want to map `case class Bonus[A: Numeric](amt: A)` over a Functor and it fails. The compilation error is

```
Error:(157, 69) could not find implicit value for evidence parameter of type Numeric[B] (No implicit Ordering defined for B.)
override def fmap[A, B](fa: Bonus[A])(f: A => B): Bonus[B] = Bonus(f(fa.amt))
```

In general, I want to fix the parameter type in `Bonus` to numbers. How do I do fix that? Thanks

The code snippet,

```
trait Functor[F[_]] {
  def fmap[A, B](fa: F[A])(f: A => B): F[B]
}

def fmap[A, B, F[_]](fa: F[A])(f: A => B)(implicit ev: Functor[F]): F[B] = ev.fmap(fa)(f)

case class Bonus[A: Numeric](amt: A)

implicit val bonusFunctor = new Functor[Bonus] {
  override def fmap[A, B](fa: Bonus[A])(f: A => B): Bonus[B] = Bonus(f(fa.amt)) // error
}

fmap(Bonus(123))(_ * 2)
```

## Update 1

Thank you **Mario** & **Dmytro** for your answers.

Dmytro, your answer is precisely as what I found at https://users.scala-lang.org/t/how-to-add-type-constraint-to-functors-map-function/2055. It makes sense that either I drop the constraint or I use a constraint Functor. I accepted Mario's answer because it shows me an alternative solution because it is not possible with Functor.

Comment: I think the problem is that `B` does not have the implicit conversion to `Numeric[B]` which is required by your `Bonus` class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
trait GFunctor[F[_], G[_]] {
  def fmap[A, B](fa: F[A])(f: A => B)(implicit ga: G[A], gb: G[B]) : F[B]
}

def fmap[A, B, F[_], G[_]](fa: F[A])(f: A => B)(implicit ev: GFunctor[F, G], ga: G[A], gb: G[B]): F[B] = ev.fmap(fa)(f)

case class Bonus[A: Numeric](amt: A)

implicit val bonusFunctor = new GFunctor[Bonus, Numeric] {
  override def fmap[A, B](fa: Bonus[A])(f: A => B)(implicit numA: Numeric[A], numbB: Numeric[B]): Bonus[B] = Bonus(f(fa.amt))
}

fmap(Bonus(123))(_ * 2)
```

which outputs

```
res0: Bonus[Int] = Bonus(246)
```

Note how we have made our typeclass solution aware of further bounds on `A` and `B` via

```
(implicit ga: G[A], gb: G[B])
```

Answer (score 5):

Instance of `Functor` type class can be defined not for any type constructor.

The fact that type constructor `F[_]` has instance of type class `Functor` means that **for any `A`, `B`**, having a function `A => B`, you know how to transform `F[A]` to `F[B]`.

But how to transform `Bonus[A]` to `Bonus[B]` **for any `A`, `B`**?

Types `Bonus[A]`, `Bonus[B]` make sense for any `A`, `B`, even if they are not `Numeric`, but creating new instance of `Bonus[B]` via constructor makes sense only for `B: Numeric`.

Either remove context bound `Numeric` in `case class Bonus[A: Numeric](amt: A)` or `Bonus` is not a `Functor`.

If you define your own type class

```
trait NumericFunctor[F[_]] {
  def fmap[A: Numeric, B: Numeric](fa: F[A])(f: A => B): F[B]
}
```

it will be not the standard functor over category of types but a custom functor over category of `Numeric` types.