# Implementing functor map for class-tagged arguments only

Tags: scala, functional-programming, functor, shapeless, scala-cats

I have the following data structure:

```
class MyDaSt[A]{

    def map[B: ClassTag](f: A => B) = //...
}
```

I'd like to implement a `Functor` instance for to be able to use ad-hoc polymorphism. The obvious attempt would be as follows:

```
implicit val mydastFunctor: Functor[MyDaSt] = new Functor[MyDaSt] {
  override def map[A, B](fa: MyDaSt[A])(f: A => B): MyDaSt[B] = fa.map(f) //compile error
}
```

It obviously does not compile because we did not provide an implicit `ClassTag[B]`. But would it be possible to use `map` only with functions `f: A => B` such that there is `ClassTag[B]`. Otherwise compile error. I mean something like that:

```
def someFun[A, B, C[_]: Functor](cc: C[A], f: A => B) = cc.map(f)

val f: Int => Int = //...
val v: MyDaSt[Int] = //...
someFunc(v, f) //fine, ClassTag[Int] exists and in scope
```

I cannot change its implementation in anyway, but I can create wrappers (which does not look helpful through) or inheritance. I'm free to use `shapeless` of any version.

I currently think that shapeless is a way to go in such case...

Comment: The short answer is you can't. First, it would be a faulty **Functor**, because it doesn't support any `A => B` but `ClassTag[B] -> A => B` _(which is a subset of the previous)_. Second, it that **Functor** if from _cats_ you can not change the signature. Finally, on your generic example, there wouldn't be a way to pass the `ClassTag` down the call.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez So declaring `map` with such signature in a data structure inhibts functor semantic....

Comment: AFAIK yes, at least one that is fully lawful. You may create your own `TaggedFunctor` whose `map` always require a **ClassTag** then you provide a `implicit def fromCatsFunctorToTaggedFunctor[F[_]](implicit functor: cats.Functor): TaggedFunctor[F] = ...` you would need to play a bit with implicit priorization and you would lose all the helper functions that _cats_ provide, but you would regain the ability to write generic functions. - PS: It would be worth asking in the cats **gitter** room if there are better ways.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59113417/numeric-map-over-with-functor

Comment: @SomeName you always can create `MyDaSt` with `def map[B: ClassTag](f: A => B)`. The question is why you need it to be a `Functor`. How would you use it if it were a `Functor`? Could you add some code? Sometimes you can use `cats.free.Coyoneda`.

Comment: @SomeName I'm asking why you need a `Functor` instance and asking to add some code of usage because now you seem actually not to need a `Functor`: `def someFun[A, B: ClassTag, C[_]](cc: MyDaSt[A], f: A => B) = cc.map(f)`.

Comment: @DmytroMitin The primary purpose is to use it in a function of the form `def foo[F[_]: Functor](dstVal: F[Int]) = //compose it` or, more generally speaking in the function that I shown in the question. Regarding your second example this is what I'm trying to avoid and abstract over the particular container `MyDaSt[A]` so it can be freely interchangeable with `List`, `Id`, etc.. Instantiating the `MyDaSt` in unit tests is tremendously cumbersome. Nice idea regarding `Coyoneda`. Could you please give some explanation, have not used it before...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll expand on what comments touched:

## Functor

`cats.Functor` describes an *endofunctor in a category of Scala types* - that is, you should be able to `map` with a function `A => B` where `A` and `B` must support any Scala types.

What you have is a mathematical functor, but in a different, smaller category of types that have a `ClassTag`. These general functors are somewhat uncommon - I think for stdlib types, only `SortedSet` can be a functor on a category of ordered things - so it's fairly unexplored territory in Scala FP right now, only rumored somewhat in Scalaz 8.

Cats does not have any tools for abstracting over such things, so you won't get any utility methods and ecosystem support. You can use [that answer linked by @DmytroMitin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59115125/2758343)  if you want to roll your own

## Coyoneda

`Coyoneda` can make an endofunctor on Scala types from any type constructor `F[_]`. The idea is simple:

- have some initial value `F[Initial]`
- have a function `Initial => A`
- to `map` with `A => B`, you don't touch initial value, but simply compose the functions to get `Initial => B`

You can lift any `F[A]` into `cats.free.Coyoneda[F, A]`. The question is how to get `F[A]` out.

If `F` is a `cats.Functor`, then it is totally natural that you can use it's native `map`, and, in fact, there will not be any difference in result with using `Coyoneda` and using `F` directly, due to functor law (`x.map(f).map(g) <-> x.map(f andThen g)`).

In your case, it's not. But you can tear `cats.free.Coyoneda` apart and delegate to your own `map`:

```scala
def coy[A](fa: MyDaSt[A]): Coyoneda[MyDaSt, A] = Coyoneda.lift(fa)
def unCoy[A: ClassTag](fa: Coyoneda[MyDaSt, A]): MyDaSt[A] =
  fa.fi.map(fa.k) // fi is initial value, k is the composed function
```

Which will let you use functions expecting `cats.Functor`:

```scala
def generic[F[_]: Functor, A: Show](fa: F[A]): F[String] = fa.map(_.show)

unCoy(generic(coy(v))) // ok, though cumbersome and needs -Ypartial-unification on scala prior to 2.13
```

(runnable example [on scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/oiynHGtvQmCogcpleXpyQA))

An obvious limitation is that you need to have a `ClassTag[A]` in any spot you want to call `unCo` - even if you did not need it to *create* an instance of `MyDaSt[A]` in the first place.

The less obvious one is that you don't automatically have that guarantee about having no behavioral differences. Whether it's okay or not depends on what your `map` does - e.g. if it's just allocating some `Array`s, it shouldn't cause issues.